# Main content height issues

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with the content and footer on a site that I am developing. On  a large screen all the content is displayed properly, but the footer doesn't have any breathing room. When I view it on a laptop, the content bleeds off the screen and you can't scroll to view it. I am not sure what to do to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the page: http://capelos.gonzbergagency.com/catering.html

Comment: please isolate your code to the question.  but from a quick look it is b/c your footer is absolute positioned (relative to the window frame instead of relative to your content), at certain size it cause conflict.

Comment: I am not sure where in the code the conflict is. I have tried to make it relative and when I do that it disappears from the screen and you can't scroll to it.

Comment: there are a ton of problems with this code(CSS).  what you have here is not wrong, but not ideal.  a quick fix you can try is to move your footer inside `.main` and 'clear:both' in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `position: absolute`, `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` from the `footer`.
2. Remove `overflow: hidden` from the `body`.
3. Remove `height: 100%` from `#catering .main`, `.main, #container` and `.content`.
4. Add an additional `div` inside the `div` with the class `main`:

`<div class="main"> 
   <!-- your other code -->
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
 </div>`

5. Change the `margin` off `.push` to `25px` instead of `100%`.

Comment: Awesome!! I was trying all these different stylings for a sticky footer and my code got really messy. Would happen to know why the content is not sitting inside the div's, it just seems to spill out of it.

Comment: You have a `float: left` and a `float: right` inside the `<div class="main">` but you never `clear` the `float`. That's the reason why this looks so strange otherwise.